# How to extract value from dynamic variables through Post

Tags: php, forms, post

I am using values to be submitted to the next page through post method. The input type fields have dynamic names which are created like this `name="fob-$id"`. Now when submitted through post, there are 4 - 5 variables such as fob-89, fob-29, fob-65 etc...
How can i assign these values to a new variable ???

NOTE: I know what numbers will be attached with the fob, so it will not be a problem, the only problem i am facing is about how to assign these values to a variable..

```
$fob=$_POST['fob-$id'];
```

Above code is not working.
Thanks

Comment: Do you want to assign all the values to one variable? Or assign all values to multiple variables?

Comment: If you know what numbers will be attached, why not `$fob89=$_POST['fob-89'];` etc? Maybe you can show us some code and an example of the expected behavior..

Comment: I Will assign values inside a loop....

Fabrico: I dont know what values are submitted, these values will be extracted from the user's session id.. so "id" will be pulled from database and if id is 23, then the submited variable would be fob-23, how can i make "-23" dynamic... i jsut want to use a variable which will fill in the number automatically...

Comment: `$fob=$_POST['fob-'.$id];` should do it, assuming `$id` is gotten from the `$_SESSION['id']`. I'm not sure how you want to implement it in a loop, I guess it'd be better to assign it to an array: `$fob[$id]=$_POST['fob-'.$id];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comment updates, assuming `$id` is an integer gotten from the `$_SESSION` var, you can store it to an array:

```
$fob[$id] = $_POST['fob-' . $id];
```

Answer (score 2):

The best way would be to name your HTML fields so that they create an array when sent back to PHP:

```
echo "<input type='text' name='fob[$id]' />";
```

And then in PHP you can just iterate over `$_POST['fob']`:

```
foreach ($_POST['fob'] as $id => $value) {
  // Do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use an array on the inputs name instead. Like this: `name="fob[$id]"`

Then you can simple do a `foreach($_POST["fob"] as $id => $value)` to get the values